# GWT.log throwing error

Tags: java, gwt

I am new to GWT and trying to build a sample application. Here is my `EntryPoint` class.

```
package com.google.gwt.sample.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;

public class TalkToServer implements EntryPoint {

  public TalkToServer() {}

  public void onModuleLoad() {
    HTTPRequest.asyncGet
      (GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "person.xml",
       new ResponseTextHandler() {
         public void onCompletion(String responseText) {
           GWT.log("some log message");
         }
       });
  }
}
```

The error here is -

```
log(java.lang.String,java.lang.Throwable) in com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)
```

I have checked gwt's javadoc and found that log can take `string` as argument. I am not able to figure out why log is throwing this error. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
GWT.log("some log message", new Throwable())
```

Comment: Thanks, This worked. But I am wondering why GWT.log("some msg") throws error

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? or any IDE?
And please mark this as answer if it worked.

Comment: I am using emacs, I have accepted this answer but can't upvote since I do not have sufficient points

Comment: In old versions of GWT, there was no `log(String)` method, only `log(String, Throwable)`. Using a newer version of GWT will give you this method.

Comment: Ok, got it, I am using gwt 2.0